# Java Get Map Of X-Y Coordinates From String

Tags: java, string, point, coordinate

Is there any way to get a map of `java.awt.Point`s from a String? Or even just a single point on that String. For example for `"xyz123\nabc123"` coordinate `(0, 1)` would be `'a'`.

Comment: Maybe it's me but I don't understand your question. How does "xyz123\nabc123" indicate that (0,2) and (1,2) are y?

Comment: Sorry I worded that badly. I changed the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built-in for that.

You can try and parse that string into a 2D char array or a vector of char arrays (depending on if you know how many lines in total or not).

Given "xyz123\nabc123" as `str`:

```
//split it by newline, should work on windows/unix
String lines[] = str.split("\\r?\\n");  
char[][] map = new char[lines.length][];
//fill up map, each row is a new line
for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i ++)
map[i] = lines[i].toCharArray();
//map[0][2] returns 'z'
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done but it's not a common representation so don't expect to find it done.

A String is not that different from a char array so these might help you:

- [Map a 2D array onto a 1D array C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2151084/422353)
- [How to convert a 1d array to 2d array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5134555/422353)

Answer (score 0):

Not going to question your motive but here is one way:

```
String find(String[] a, int x, int y) {
    try {
        return String(a[x].charAt(y));   // or y+1 in your example
    }
    catch (Exception exc) {
        return NULL; 
    }
}
...

String s = "xyz123\nabc546";
String[] sa = s.split("\\n");

find(sa, 0, 0);  // returns "x"
find(sa, 1, 2);  // returns "c"
find(sa, 3, 2);  // returns NULL
```