# Storing a Matrix in array

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I'm trying to make the bidimensional Matrix as an ADT. So given the interface `Matrix<T>` talking about like a bidimensional array. So I can achieve implement this Interface using a bidimensional Arrar `Object[][] matrix` as background. Now, I'm trying to implement the interface with an array `Object[] matrix` as background (i.e. Storing the matrix within an array). I found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956756/java-how-to-store-a-2d-array-within-a-1d-array) how to store a 2D array withn a 1D array, I want to do the same, but without using the 2D array. I'm limited to not use list. So any suggestion?

EDIT: input some code.

```
/* 
* T is a data type which extends the Operable(self-defined) interface
* We're thinking about a numerical matrix so, other operations are the sum, the product etc etc.
* The idea is to make the operations in terms of the backgorund, which in the two- dimensional is pretty easy. But in a unidimensional array?
*/

//Bidimensional background

public class ArrayedMatrix<T extends Operable> implements Matrix<T> {

private Object[][] matrix;


public ArrayedMatrix(int rows, int cols) {
    matriz = new Object[rows][cols];
}


public ArrayedMatrix(T[][] matriz) {
    this.matrix = matriz;
}

//Unidimensional Background
public class LinearMatrix<T extends Operable> implements Matrix<T> {

Object[] matrix;
int rows,cols;

public LinearMatrix(int n, int m) {
    matriz = new Object[n*m];
    rows = n;
    cols = m;

}
//Temporal constructor, this is the one i want to edit
public LinearMatrix(Object[][] mat){
    rows = mat.length;
    cols = mat[0].length;
    matrix = new Object[rows*cols];
    for (int row = 0, count = 0; row < rows ; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < cols ; col++) {
        matriz[count] = mat[row][col];
        count++;
    }
}
}
```

Okay, the matter is, if I define the constructor of the Matrix with the 2D array as parameter, every operation will be less efficent than expected, so I want to make a constructor with another kind of collection as parameter.

Comment: Just edited @Emma

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How to store a 2D array within a 1D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956756/java-how-to-store-a-2d-array-within-a-1d-array)

Comment: your difficult to read code does not make this question anything else. define `public class Matrix` and then use `ArrayList<Matrix>`.

Comment: Do you have any concrete question? Any error or issue that you are facing?

Comment: @MartinZeitler I've just referenced that question lol.

Comment: What is wrong with using `Object[][] mat` as parameter? With any collection as parameter you'd still need to copy the elements to construct the `LinearMatrix`; not much room for performance improvement there. That said you should be able to use any ordered collection as long as #rows and #cols are implicitly or explicitly specified.

Answer (score 1):

Any 2d array can be represented as a 1d array by just "unwrapping" the rows and remembering the number of columns (i.e. the width). For example:

```
int[] grid = new int[width * height];

int get(int row, int column) {
    return grid[row * this.width + column];
}
```