# How to convert ArrayList to Array 2 dimension in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to convert ArrayList to Array 2-Dimension

**I have the code below:**

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList();
arrayList.add("A")
arrayList.add("B")
arrayList.add("C")
arrayList.add("D")
arrayList.add("E")
arrayList.add("F")

int nSize=0,n3item=0, remain=0;
nSize=arrayList.size();
n3item=nSize/3;
remain=nSize%3;
String[][] array[n3item][3]

I want to convert ArrayList to array for example
array[0][1]="A"
array[0][2]="B"
array[0][3]="C"
array[1][1]="D"
array[1][2]="E"
array[1][3]="F"
```

Now I haven't a solution to do this. 
In case of remain is not 0. How to give a solution to this problem
I need your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a 1d array to 2d array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134555/how-to-convert-a-1d-array-to-2d-array)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple nested for-loop to achieve this.

```
int numCol = 3;
int numRow = (int) Math.ceil(arrayList.size() / ((double) numCol));
String[][] array = new String[numRow][numCol];

int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < numRow; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3 && (i * numCol + j) < arrayList.size(); j++) {
        array[i][j] = arrayList.get((i * numCol) + j);
    }
}
```

`numRow` is found by taking the *ceil* of number of elements in the list divided by num of desired columns. 
eg - when arraylist has 7 elements, `numRow` will be *ceil(7/3.0) = 3*.

The main trick here is in the inner for-loop condition `(i * numCol + j) < arrayList.size()`. It enables us to terminate the loop for the condition `remain != 0` you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try to think, how you can fill the 2D array with arraylist values. You need to use a nested loop for assigning the values into the 2D array. Outer loop will iterate over the rows and inner loop will fill the values into each 1D array.

```
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n3item; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        array[i][j] = arrayList.get(index);
        index++;
    }
}
```